# AutoHotkey `Ctrl+` combination hiding `Ctrl+Alt+` combination from other app

Tags: autohotkey

On Windows 10 I'm using AutoHotkey 2. Let's say that in Firefox I want to map `Ctrl+F` (for "Find") to the `Ctrl+E` combination, to select the Firefox search bar. It looks like this:

```
#HotIf WinActive("ahk_exe firefox.exe")
^f::^e
#HotIf
```

That works fine. But let's say that I have some global "Finder" program installed on my system that detects the `Ctrl+Alt+F` combination and pops up when that hotkey is pressed. When I turn on the `Ctrl+F` Autohotkey definition above, when I'm in Firefox somehow that prevents my "Finder" program from seeing the `Ctrl+Alt+F` combination.

Is this a bug in AutoHotkey, or is there some way to tweak the `Ctrl+F` mapping so as not to hide the `Ctrl+Alt+F` combination from other applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remapping](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/misc/Remap.htm) doesn't release the modifier keys, because it uses the [blind](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm#Blind) mode.
Try the Send command:

```
#HotIf WinActive("ahk_exe firefox.exe")

    ^f::Send "^e"

#HotIf
```

Comment: That works!! Thank you so much. I'll have to admit, reading the documentation, that the specifics of blind mode get a little intricate. Is there any downside or any caveats to using the `Send` command? Any gotchas I need to watch out for? Or to put it another way, why wouldn't I want to use `Send` for all my remappings (or at least those involving `Ctrl`, `Alt`, `Shift`, and/or `Win`)?

Comment: Depending on the case, each Send mode and remapping has its place and justification. In combinations its best to use the Send command. Using the keyboard hook ([#UseHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_UseHook.htm)) is important to make the hotkeys not trigger each other.